# Flutter table_calendar add holiday to calendar

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, android-calendar

I have a list of objects that have fields of `date` and `daytype` which the `daytype`is used to determine whether the date is a holiday or a working day. I am using `TableCalendar` from `table_calender` in my app. I am trying to show the holiday on the calendar using `event loader` but the calendar indicates the holiday dates with markers. The image attached is my expected results (style the date with a purple box):

[image]

Anyone can give me any idea on how to achieve this?

** My holiday might not always on every Saturday and Sunday